# Update with select the same table [mysql]

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

can you guys help me to update the table with select the same table?
My table:

```
id | pass_date           | daydiff |
1  | 2018-04-20 14:49:24 |         |
2  | 2018-04-21 14:49:24 |         |
3  | 2018-04-20 14:49:24 |         |
```

I can select the table to count the daydiff

```
SELECT id, DATEDIFF(pass_date , CURDATE()) as daydiff  FROM users
```

Result:

```
id | daydiff  |
1  |    3     |
2  |    2     |
3  |    3     |
```

What I wanna to do is to update the daydiff column like this:

```
id | pass_date           | daydiff |
1  | 2018-04-20 14:49:24 |    3    |
2  | 2018-04-21 14:49:24 |    2    |
3  | 2018-04-20 14:49:24 |    3    |
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do the following

```
update table_name set day_diff = DATEDIFF(pass_date , CURDATE());
```